# Solving for point P within the edge AC, given points A, B and C, and length from B to P?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, triangles

[image: The triangle with desired point P]

(EDIT: one of the comments noted that AC is too short in the image, this is completely my fault for not checking before rounding, therefor replace the magnitude of AC to, say 10)

So given points A B and C we can calculate the magnitudes of AB, AC, and CB, and
we know there is a point in the line of AC that has the distance of, say 60 like in the image,
to the point B. What are the necessary steps to solve for point P?

Comment: What is "this problem", and what have you tried? Note that the 2-58-61 triangle cannot exist.

Comment: Sorry, solving the point P. I've tried basic triangle calculus from here: https://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html?vc=&vx=61&vy=2&va=&vz=58&vb=&angleunits=r&x=68&y=23, but I don't seem to get them to work in this case... correct me if I am wrong, it has been a while since I did anything with trigonometry.

Comment: The error message reads "The sum of two sides must be larger than the third." This is because your triangle violates the triangle inequality.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Silly me for not taking it into account when rounding up the values. I will correct the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [the Stewart’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)
in its puriest form:

\begin{align} 
|BC|^2\cdot|AP|+
|AB|^2\cdot(|AC|-|AP|)
=|AC|\cdot(|BP|^2+|AP|\cdot(|AC|-|AP|))
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
|AP|&=
\frac{|AB|^2+|AC|^2-
|BC|^2\pm\sqrt{\Big(|AB|^2-|BC|^2\Big)^2-|AC|^2\cdot\Big(2|BC|^2+2|AB|^2-|AC|^2-4|BP|^2\Big)}}
{2|AC|}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

for given $|AB|=61$, $|BC|=58$, $|BP|=60$, $|AC|=10$
\eqref{2} gives

\begin{align} 
|AP|&=\tfrac1{20}(457\pm\sqrt{160449})
\end{align}

with the only valid root

\begin{align} 
|AP|&=\tfrac1{20}(457-\sqrt{160449})
\approx 2.82
.
\end{align}

Edit

Note that for some set of side lengths
there are indeed two valid solutions,
for example if
we have $|AB|=61$, $|BC|=58$, $|BP|=55$, $|AC|=60$,
the expressions

\begin{align} 
|AP_+|&=\tfrac1{40}\,(1319+\sqrt{626161})
\approx 52.7576
\\
\text{and }\quad
|AP_-|&=\tfrac1{40}\,(1319-\sqrt{626161})
\approx 13.1924
\end{align}
are valid and give two points as the answer:

\begin{align} 
P_+&=A+\frac{|AP_+|}{|AC|}\cdot(C-A)
,\\
P_-&=A+\frac{|AP_-|}{|AC|}\cdot(C-A)
,
\end{align}

see the picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, and for the provided link of the calculus. Also I appreaciate all of the steps that your answer shows. I did notice that there are cases which can have two answers, but was happy to come back to this thread and see that question also already answered! Big upvote, if I yet could..

Answer (score 0):

The 'basic triangle calculus' you are referring to are the Law of Sines and Cosines. In this particular example, we apply the Law of Cosines twice. We have:

$$AB^2 = AC^2+CB^2-2AC\cdot CB \cos\angle ACB$$

which gives

$$\cos \angle ACB = \frac {10^2+58^2-61^2}{2\cdot10\cdot58}=-\frac {257}{1160}$$

Now we also have from Law of Cosines:

$$BP^2 = PC^2+CB^2-2PC\cdot CB\cos\angle ACB$$

with $BP=60, BC =58$, the equation above is just a quadratic equation in $PC$, which we can solve by the quadratic formula. Here is [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=60%5E2+%3D+x%5E2%2B58%5E2-2x*58*%2810%5E2%2B58%5E2-61%5E2%29%2F%2820*58%29) taking a crack at it.

Answer (score 0):

Note
\begin{align}
AP &= AB \cos A -BP \cos \angle BPC \\
&= AB \cos A -BP \sqrt{ 1- \sin^2 \angle BPC}\\
&= AB \cos A -BP \sqrt{ 1- \sin^2 \angle BPA} \\
 &= AB \cos A -BP \sqrt{ 1- \frac{AB^2}{BP^2}\sin^2A}\>\>\>\>\>\>\>(sine \>rule)\\
 &= AB \cos A -\sqrt{ BP^2 - {AB^2}(1-\cos^2A)}\\
\end{align}
where $AB$ and $BP$ are given and from the cosine rule
$$\cos A =\frac{AB^2+AC^2-BC^2}{2\cdot AB\cdot AC}
$$